# Problem adding layers with REST Services in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

This is my first question in this forum and I'm not sure if it is going to be properly structured. I've asked same question in other forum but I did not receive any response. I'll see if I have good luck here!

My problem happens when I want to upload a GeoTiff using the Import Data plugin through REST Services. I can't override same layer, method create a new one. But I need to keep same name for each update.

I'm using cURL commands to call the REST services.

## 1. Creating a new import

```
curl -k -u admin:pwd -XPOST -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d @import.json 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/imports'
```

where @import.json is:

```
{
   "import": {
      "targetWorkspace": {
         "workspace": {
            "name": "SIHA"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

## 2. Creating a new task (in this case import_id = 0)

```
curl -k -u admin:pwd -F name=test -F filedata=@file201510.tif 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/imports/0/tasks'
```

## 3. Running the task

```
curl -k -u admin:pwd -XPOST 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/imports/0'
```

At first time, it works perfectly. But when I've tried to call these commands again the name change ending with a sequence. (file2015100, file2015101, file2015102)

I've tried to delete the layer previously, but without success:

```
curl -k -u admin:pwd -XDELETE http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/file201510
```

Layer is deleted properly but the new layer is created following the same strange pattern (adding a sequence at the end of the name)

Also, I've tried to force the updateMode, but without success as well.

```
curl -k -u admin:pwd -XPUT -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d @replace.json 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/imports/0/tasks/0'
```

where @replace.json is:

```
{
  "task": {
     "updateMode": "REPLACE"
  }
}
```

I hope that you understand my problem and someone could help to solve it.